# Am I using crypt and mcrypt well in this simple encryption class?

Tags: php, security, cryptography

These days I read a lot here on SO about password hashing and data encryption. It's a real mess, I mean, deciding what the best practice is. I need a very simple class that can be reused anywhere and that provide a ***decent-but-not-paranoic*** security level for my PHP applications (I do not handle bank data). Additionally, I want to rely as much as possible on PHP standard libs. I came up with this:

```
class Security {

    public static function hashPassword($plain) {
        $salt = md5(rand(0, 1023) . '@' . time()); // Random salt
        return crypt($plain, '$2a$07$' . $salt); // '$2a$07$' is the Blowfish trigger
    }

    public static function checkPassword($plain, $hash) {
        return (crypt($plain, $hash) === $hash);
    }

    public static function generateIv() {
        $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC); // It's 32
        return mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
    }

    public static function encrypt($key, $data, $iv = null, $base64 = true) {
        if (is_null($iv)) $iv = md5($key);
        $ret = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
        return ($base64 ? base64_encode($ret) : $ret);
    }

    public static function decrypt($key, $data, $iv = null, $base64 = true) {
        if (is_null($iv)) $iv = md5($key);
        return rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $base64 ? base64_decode($data) : $data, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv), "\0");
    }

}
```

As you can see, I choose to hash passwords with [**`crypt()`**](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) using **Blowfish hashing algorithm**. The return value of `hashPassword()` is the salt + hash that then I store in the DB. I made this choice because `crypt()` is available on every server, provides a confortable way to check hash regardless of algorithm used (it's based on salt prefix) and, I read, *bcrypt* is a decent hashing method.

Then, for data encryption I used [**`mcrypt()`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php) **Rijndael 256** algorithm with **CBC mode**. As you can see, I can use encryption methods in two way. I can pass a IV (and `generateIv()` helps me to create one) that I will store in the DB along crypted data, or, if I don't, a basic IV is derived from key in both crypt and decrypt process.

What do you think about it? Am I missing something? Can I be finally relaxed about hashing and encryption in my PHP applications?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your salt generation mechanism does not seem sufficiently random. You will end up with a very small set of salts.

First of all, `time()` is not random at all. In second place, `rand(0, 1023)` is not only a relatively weak random number generator, but also generates too few bits to be enough.

All this - combined with the use of the relatively unsafe `md5` algorithm - means that there's a higher-than-ideal risk of salt collision.

Will all of this still cause trouble? Frankly, I don't know. This is definitely better than storing passwords in plain text, or using unsalted hashes, but it's not perfect. Generally, I'm nervous about using not-exactly-random data for security algorithms that are meant to use random data.

For a starting point, try to look at [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795385/how-do-you-use-bcrypt-for-hashing-passwords-in-php). This is what the author does for salt generation:

1. Use OpenSSL random pseudo bytes, if available. Using a security library to get random data for use in another security function makes me far less nervous than ordinary `rand()`.
2. Try a *NIX-specific method
3. If not possible, then use a mix of `md5`, `microtime`(better than `time` since it changes more often) and even the PID.

In particular, note than PHP's `md5` normally returns a hexadecimal string with a 32-byte length, but `bcrypt` expects a string with a length of `22`, so that might cause troubles (namely, the salt will not be as secure as it could be)

Also, in your case this won't be a problem, but `$2a` is ambiguous (but sadly, the correct, unambiguous way might be incompatible with older PHP versions). If you can, consider using `$2y` instead and see if that works for you.

The PHP documentation [recommends](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-get-iv-size.php) using `mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size` instead of `mcrypt_get_iv_size` and using that in combination with `mcrypt_module_open` (although strangely, the [documentation for `mcrypt_encrypt`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php) does use `mcrypt_get_iv_size`)

Again, you are using not-really-random data for a function that seems to expect random data (specifically, the IV when the supplied IV is "null"). This makes me nervous.

Comment: Thank you @luiscubal for your remarks. It's all little changes I can do without class skeleton modifications and, most important, without break compatibility for already-used cases (that means, ok, salts and IVs will be better than previous from now, but old stuff will continue to work with updated class too). I will try to use `mt_rand()` with no args (that means, *0 to 2^31* on 32 bits systems) instead of `rand(0, 1023)` and `microtime()` instead of time. I think that will be sufficient.

Comment: @lorenzo-s Please consider using SSL random pseudo bytes, if available, or reading from `/dev/urandom`. Rely on the other options (`mt_rand` and `microtime`) only if *really* necessary. Better safe than sorry.